# Overriding virtual function not get called in Unity C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote the following 2 scripts in Unity 3D , `PhysicsObject` and `PlayerPlatformerController` (following this [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/player-controller-script?playlist=17093)). The `PlayerPlatformerController` script is attached to a game object.

**PhysicsObject.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PhysicsObject : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update () {
        ComputeVelocity ();
    }

    protected virtual void ComputeVelocity() {

    }
}
```

**PlayerPlatformerController.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPlatformerController : PhysicsObject {
    void Update () {

    }

    protected override void ComputeVelocity() {

    }
}
```

The codes look simple, but the `ComputeVelocity()` in `PlayerPlatformerController` does not get called (proved by adding `Debug.Log()`). Why?

If I change to the following codes, the function works perfectly:

**PhysicsObject.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PhysicsObject : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update () {
        //ComputeVelocity ();
    }

    /*protected virtual void ComputeVelocity() {

    }*/
}
```

**PlayerPlatformerController.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPlatformerController : PhysicsObject {
    void Update() {
         ComputeVelocity();
    }

    void ComputeVelocity() {

    }
}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Is the `ComputeVelocity` method being called in `PhysicsObject`?

Comment: Hi Steve, yes, the `ComputeVelocity()` can be called within `PhysicsObject` (also proven by `Debug.Log()`)

Comment: Try changing `ComputeVelocity` in `PhysicsObject` to be an abstract method to see if it's called in `PlayerPlatformerController`. I'm coming from a .Net view but unless Mono has a different behaviour this should be working as you expect.

Comment: Thanks. By changing the `virtual` to `abstract`, it requires `PhysicsObject` class to be an `abstract` class as well. Since I have other codes in the `PhysicsObject` class, I can't do so. I start thinking this is a glitch of Unity, as my codes look fine, no matter from .NET or Mono framework perspective.

Comment: You should be able to make 'PhysicsObject' abstract if you're not using it directly. I only suggested it to test anyway to see if the base implementation gets called at all.

Comment: Is this the entire code for `PlayerPlatformerController`?

Comment: And have you double checked that you got a `PlayerPlatformerController` and not a `PhysicsObject` attached to the gameobject?

Comment: @Kits The codes are identical to the ones in tutorial links. You can check the full codes in the link in question. Thanks. And yes, I double checked it's a `PlayerPlatformerController`

Comment: @Raptor I just setup the project from the tutorial link and it works correctly for me. Make sure both files are saved and there are no errors in the console. Maybe copy over the code from the tutorial onto your files in case you made a typo or something similar. Also, as Kits said, double check that only `PlayerPlatformerController` is assigned to the Player game object, not `PhysicsObject`. Finally, if you're using VIsual Studio, try putting a break point in both files to see what's getting hit and what's not.

Comment: I'm using MonoDevelop. What is your Unity 3D version?

Comment: Are you sure your code call PhysicsObject.Update()? You can try to add two new classes, that caontains only Update() and ComputeVelocity() methods, and if they will be work correctly you can step by step add functionality, and debug it each step. In this way you can find a problem. Problem difinitely not apply to the IDE and Unity version.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me that I had two scripts:
Health.cs
HealthModified.cs -> This was overriding function of Health.cs

In my GameObject I was testing HealthModified (enabled) and I also had the Health.cs in the gameobject but disabled.

The code was using the Halth.cs compoenent also when it was disabled, I had to remove the component from the gameobject to get the HealthModified behaviour.

Comment: I only have the `PlayerPlatformerController` script component with my game object; the `PhysicsObject` is not included in the game object's component list.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen because you use Update method in child-class (PlayerPlatformerController). If it true, you will mark update as protected and virtual, and override it in child class. It may look like this:

```
public class PhysicsObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        ComputeVelocity();
        Debug.LogFormat("PhysicsObject Update");
    }

    protected virtual void ComputeVelocity()
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("PhysicsObject ComputeVelocity");
    }
}


public class PlayerPlatformerController : PhysicsObject
{
    protected override void Update()
    {
        base.Update();
        Debug.LogFormat("PlayerPlatformerController Update");
    }

    protected override void ComputeVelocity()
    {
        base.ComputeVelocity();
        Debug.LogFormat("PlayerPlatformerController ComputeVelocity");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the problem. In the `PlayerPlatformerController` class, if I remove the `Update()` method, the override `ComputeVelocity()` will start working.

Thanks all for your efforts helping me.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a class that inherits from another you need to be wary of accidentally overriding the parent's methods.

In this case, creating empty Start() and Update() methods will replace those from the parent. This is an easy mistake to make since new classes are normally created with those methods by default.

Removing the methods from the child class will ensure the parent is called instead. Or if you want to keep the child methods while also calling the parent's, you can use `base.Start()` (or whichever method you are overriding).